# Ubuntu 20.04 Major problem with bluetooth

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, bluez

I am super new to using Ubuntu and I do not know much about it, but in the last few days I am experiencing a major problem with Bluetooth as the command does not work at all, I tried to start it from the terminal and does not work, does not connect, I tried to reboot bluez many times but every time I start the PC appears a notification that says "Daemon Bluez not active"

I know that is a situation that occurred to many people but I was not able yet to find a working solution...
Thank you for helping me

Edit, Results for:

> lusub

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6730 Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 10c4:8108 Silicon Labs USB OPTICAL MOUSE
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

> sudo dmesg |egrep -i 'blue|firm'

```
[    1.824783] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_12.bin (v2.12)
    [    7.529282] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: Firmware version 24.8.0, H2C version 12
    [  102.387004] audit: type=1400 audit(1686576929.516:130): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2029 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [  102.391891] audit: type=1400 audit(1686576929.524:131): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=2028 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
    [  102.391977] audit: type=1400 audit(1686576929.524:132): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2028 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [  102.595483] audit: type=1400 audit(1686576929.728:133): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2109 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [  102.595988] audit: type=1400 audit(1686576929.728:134): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=2108 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
    [  102.596106] audit: type=1400 audit(1686576929.728:135): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2108 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [  102.769398] audit: type=1400 audit(1686576929.900:136): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=2186 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
    [  102.769519] audit: type=1400 audit(1686576929.900:137): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2186 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [  102.770767] audit: type=1400 audit(1686576929.900:138): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=2187 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [  106.515509] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
    [  106.515531] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
    [  106.515532] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
    [  106.515535] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
    [  106.515537] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
    [  106.515539] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
    [  114.556546] audit: type=1107 audit(1686576941.688:149): pid=1222 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=3112 label="snap.skype.skype"
    [  141.103693] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
    [  141.103696] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
    [  141.103700] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
    [  350.006168] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
    [ 1196.089615] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lsusb; sudo dmesg |egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I apologize for the format, I'm an idiot and idk how to put it properly, but these are the results asap I find the proper way to format it I ll do that

Comment: ok should be formatted properly now, tnx for having a look at that

Comment: Did Bluetooth ever work?

Comment: @Jeremy31 yes, just the last week it has not been working. I hope to have not caused a major damage in my attempt to fix it

Comment: Try shutting it off, remove power cord, then hold the power button for 30 seconds, connect power cord and boot